# Obtain NON-EXPIRING access token for a Facebook Page

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, token

i would obtain (trought whatever Facebook API for Java) a non-expiring access token for my page; i've followed some other guides on stackoverflow but no one works for me.

I need to do an autologin, and obtain the non-expiring access token, without using the web!

What's the best way ?

Actually i have just a page id, secret and login credentials

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the Graph API endpoint

```
/me/accounts
```

Be sure to have a User AccessToken which has manage_page permisions.

Try it here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts

To use this via JS SDK look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart#graphapi

Sample code:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=accounts.fields(id,name,access_token)', function(response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

Comment: uhm, i want to do all without using web pages! Just using java (login also) or php!

Comment: I read that. But you didn't specify which "Facebook API for Java" you use, so how should one give you a good example? There is no official FB Java API, so you either need to find another one like http://restfb.com/ or you need to switch to the official PHP SDK. And: Be sure to be friendly to people which try to help you

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but every api/tecnology is good... i want to know just (with whatever technology) if there is a method, in java or php, to login and obtain non-expiring access token without using web! Many Thanks!

Comment: Just read the documentation which is available under the links I posted above. I added some sample code as well. "Without using web" is a little bit strange, because in the background the Graph API will be called via HTTPS from every SDK you'll find!

Comment: I'll read it! Without using web, about me, means that i wont show the facebook login and execute a method (java or php). For example: FBLogin.connect('username','password') and it return me the access token... in this method i'll not show the login form, because i want to do this automatically.